# Compute correlation *only* between specific combinations of indices in python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, correlation

I'm trying to compute some correlations between variables stored in a 2D numpy array (integer values, dimension: `n_variables * n_observations` ).

e.g.:

```
data = np.array([
    [1,3,7,5,6],
    [2,3,4,5,2],
    [3,3,9,5,10],
    [4,3,4,8,6],])
```

I have thus a "mask array" (boolean values, dimension: `n_variable * n_variables`) indicating pairs of variables I'm interested in, which has no apriori pattern. Each variable can also have a different number of occurences.

e.g.: V1 & V2, V1 & V3, V3 & V4.

```
potential_corr =  np.array([
    [0,1,1,0],
    [1,0,0,0],
    [1,0,0,1],
    [0,0,1,0],])
```

Is there a way to compute correlation (or apply an other function) for only these specific combinations of index ?

The matrix I'm looking at has more than 100K variables and the same order of observations, I'm thus really trying to use this filter before the correlations' calculations for some computational time and memory optimisation.

I'm not really used to not mainstream numpy usage, and didn't find functions to realise such 'sparse' calculations.
I thought I could use take_along_axis but if I'm not mistaking, each variable would then be stored as many times as the number of combinations it's present in. That didn't look like a good idea to me, memory-wise.

I'm of course looking for any solution relevant for my problem, I don't absolutely want to use numpy arrays if other data format could be appropriate.

Thanks a lot for your help !

Rémi

Comment: For sparse array computation in general, look into Scipy, which has a sparse array module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution, which calculates the means and the standard deviations *only* once:

```
def calculate_corr_for_pairs(data, mask):
    n_vars, n_obs = data.shape

    means = np.mean(data, axis=1)
    stds = np.std(data, axis=1, ddof=1)

    results = []

    pairs_idx = np.nonzero(mask)

    for i, j in zip(*pairs_idx):
        xi = data[i, :] - means[i]
        xj = data[j, :] - means[j]
        corr = np.sum(xi * xj) / ((n_obs - 1) * stds[i] * stds[j])
        results.append({f'V_{i+1}, V_{j+1}': corr})

    return results

idx = np.triu(potential_corr)

calculate_corr_for_pairs(data, idx)
```

---

Another possible solution (but not as efficient as the previous one, because it repeats the calculations of the means and standard deviations):

```
idx = np.nonzero(np.triu(potential_corr))
[{f'V_{i+1}, V_{j+1}': np.corrcoef(data[i,:], data[j,:])[0,1]} 
 for i,j in zip(idx[0], idx[1])]
```

---

Output:

```
[{'V_1, V_2': 0.44585082870893733},
 {'V_1, V_3': 0.8763704002132351},
 {'V_3, V_4': 0.26382242650554316}]
```